# How to use jquery using @types in angular2 project

Tags: angular

I  did following things,

```
1) npm install --save-dev jquery

2) npm install --save-dev @types/jquery

3) tsconfig.json

"types": [
      "jquery",
    ]

4) in component,

import * as $ from 'jquery';

$('#myCarousel').carousel("next");
```

> error : [ts] property carousel does not exist on type 'JQuery'.

What is missing?

Comment: Try `npm install --save-dev @types/jquery` or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20430922/the-property-jqgrid-does-not-exist-on-value-of-type-jquery

Comment: @yurzui it is @types/jquery only. Its a typo...thanks btw !!!